# Could a good poker-playing AI be made that didn't look at its own cards?

Tags: game-ai, poker, card-games

A bit ago, I found out that [researchers had taught a machine to play Texas Hold'Em](https://www.zdnet.com/article/machine-learning-goes-beyond-theory-to-beat-human-poker-champs/) at a level that beat most champions. However, that AI had access to the information of what cards it was dealt.

So I got to wondering. If a poker-playing AI were made, where the AI did not know what its own cards were (that is, it never 'looked' at them), would it be possible for the AI to reach a similar level of success?

Comment: Please, ask only one question per post. The fact that you put 2 questions in the title (instead of one) is a good indication that you probably should split this post into multiple ones! Please, edit your post to fix this issue.

Comment: Part of why I'm asking is that if the answer to the above question is 'yes', it segues into a question about whether you could teach a *human* to play Poker at a high skill level without ever looking at their cards. (Though if the other humans noticed this, they might change their behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

If the AI does not know its own cards, it only has less knowledge and is therefore at a disadvantage. The AI could only act on the basis of the other players' play, while they know their own cards and can use the information.

For example, if you look at a game with 2 players before any action was taken, from the AI's point of view the chance of winning would be 50% while the other player can calculate a much more precise probability based on his own cards and build on that.

A super-human level cannot be reached with this.

If the strategy is cleverly adapted, a beginner level can perhaps be reached.